# Pretty Print JSON with JBuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

I am using JBuilder as a JSON DSL. I have it working properly but cannot figure out how to pretty print JSON.

I want to use JSON.pretty_generate but that requires a string or a hash, and JBuilder is a custom JBuilder object that does not convert.

Any ideas how to pretty print JSON with JBuilder template?

Comment: a solution/workaround is available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13128485/pretty-print-json-generated-with-a-jbuilder-template-in-rails-3-2-8

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing the JBuilder output, then using JSON.pretty_generate on that resulting output

```
json_builder = Jbuilder.encode do |json|
  ... your json.data ...
end

json_obj = JSON.parse(json_builder)
puts       JSON.pretty_generate(json_obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

I use pretty output for all my JSON in development by using an initializer for multi_json (the current backend for jbuilder):

In `config/initializers/multi_json.rb`

```
require 'multi_json'

MultiJson.dump_options = { pretty: true } if Rails.env.development?
```